# i'm having a code that is replacing files and checks files with a specific string(path) and i want to make it dynamic t c#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, c#-4.0

I want to change my function from an static way to dynamic in which this is the code that is static :

```
string level0path = Application.StartupPath + "/games/Militia/Militia_Data/level0";

string address = "https://test.com/LauncherLogin/Games/MILITIA/Militia_Data/";

HttpWebRequest level0pathR = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(address + "level0");
level0pathR.Method = "HEAD";
long level0len;
using (HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)(level0pathR.GetResponse()))
{
       level0len = resp.ContentLength / 1024;
}

if (File.Exists(level0path))
{
      FileInfo level0Vol = new FileInfo(level0path);
      long level0length = 0;

      if (level0Vol.Length >= (1 << 10))
      {
           level0length = level0Vol.Length >> 10;
      }

      if (level0len > level0length)
      {
         MessageBox.Show("levl0");
         custimizedProgressBar1.Value = 0;
         label15.Show();
         File.Delete(Application.StartupPath + "/games/Militia/Militia_Data/level0");
         Level0Download();
      }
      else if (level0len < level0length)
      {
         label15.Show();
         File.Delete(Application.StartupPath + "/games/Militia/Militia_Data/level0");
         Level0Download();
      }
      else if (level0len == level0length)
      {
         // Nothing
      }
}
```

This code is making a check for the file on host and file on local disk and determines if there is a difference. If there's a difference in the filesize, the file is downloaded, otherwise nothing happens.

As you can see it's made with variables for the place of files.

I want to make it search for files in a specific path and make variables and make everything automatic to make it more small and make the code more smaller any help

Comment: There's a lot to unpack here.  If I gave you twelve words to describe what it is that you want to accomplish, what would those twelve words be?  Hint: Don't talk about code; just talk about your objective.

Comment: Some observations: 1.  I don't know what you mean by `static` and `dynamic.`  2.  If you're trying to determine if a file on disk has changed, its size is not a reliable indicator.  Checking the date time stamp of the file is better.

Comment: static : i mean the code is made by strings like string for file on host string for file on local disk and variable for file size and variable etc all of these are written i want it to be all searchinf files and get the local files by browsing by code then he makes varaibales for founded files and the filename for every path he found and put it in the addres of host that contain the same file in disk and this to make it more small.

Comment: thanks for your tips i will try to make with it.

Comment: but my English is not the best maybe I write words not the wanted words for the sentence

Comment: Are you actually working with `[c#-4.0]` released in April 2010 as your added Tag seems to indicate?

Comment: not sure the difference but i found it's the latest one so i put it. i'm working with .net core 3.1 c# vs19

Comment: That would be C# version 8.0, which does not have an own SO tag so far, see also 

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_(programming_language)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/configure-language-version

Comment: thanks for this helpful information, I checked It and it was very useful.

Answer (score 0):

Currently you check the file size of the file level0 in the directory Militia_Data. I assume you want to check also the other files that are in the directory? Then you need to run over the directory files:

```
public void test()
{
   var militiaData = $"{MediaTypeNames.Application.StartupPath}/games/Militia/Militia_Data/";
   var militiaDataDirectoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(militiaData);
   var levelFiles = militiaDataDirectoryInfo.GetFiles("level*",SearchOption.AllDirectories); // get all files that starts with level also from sub folders, if you need all files then *.*
   foreach (var levelFile in levelFiles)
   {
      CheckFile(levelFile.Name);
   }
}

private void CheckFile(string levelFile)
{
   string level0path = $"{MediaTypeNames.Application.StartupPath}/games/Militia/Militia_Data/{levelFile}";

   string address = "https://test.com/LauncherLogin/Games/MILITIA/Militia_Data/";

   HttpWebRequest level0pathR = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(address + levelFile);
   level0pathR.Method = "HEAD";
   long level0len;
   using (HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)(level0pathR.GetResponse()))
   {
     level0len = resp.ContentLength / 1024;
   }

   if (File.Exists(level0path))
   {
     FileInfo level0Vol = new FileInfo(level0path);
  long level0length = 0;

    if (level0Vol.Length >= (1 << 10))
    {
      level0length = level0Vol.Length >> 10;
    }

    if (level0len > level0length)
    {
      MessageBox.Show(levelFile);
      custimizedProgressBar1.Value = 0;
      label15.Show();
      File.Delete(level0path);
      Level0Download();
    }
  else if (level0len < level0length)
  {
    label15.Show();
    File.Delete(level0path);
    Level0Download();
  }
  else if (level0len == level0length)
  {
    // Nothing
  }
}
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, ok but i want this to make on all directories and subdirectories in militia_Data and in the download function how can i make it download the file that is on host to take the path of the file on desk and take the part of filename and put it in the address variable to get the link of the version on the host and download it if the file size was diff

Comment: to get the file from the sub directories I update the example SearchOption.AllDirectories. The link is already updated in the example. levelFile contains the name of the file that is found in the directory. In you example the file name was hard coded now it is dynamical depending from what is in the directory.

Comment: there is a problem when he gets filename he gets him without the extenstion so he dont recognize it so do you have a soulition?

Comment: sure if you have a look in the levelFile object there is a property extension, that is the file extension. then you can add the extension to the string before you call the method

Comment: thanks very much, but there is another problem i got into when he downloads many files he downloads all of them in same time then he made web client timed out error how can i make it when file downloads he get into the other file

Comment: help i still getting a problem